# How to avoid code duplication for two identical Vue apps in one page?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, code-duplication

I have a page where I'd like to use two nearly identical Vue apps. They will have just a simple table with some status info and a few `input`s. The only thing in which they differ is the id of the table. I have a separate function which feeds them data and is called (in a callback of the status being downloaded) with the Vue app as one of its parameters.

So now I have two Vue apps in the script, above each other, and 48/50 lines are identical (and I can expect them to grow). They have each a few `data` elements, a few `methods` and one `computed`. How could I avoid such an awful code duplication?

My solution so far is to predefine the `data`, `computed`, `methods` (`pre_...`), and then do just:

```
var app1 = new Vue({
  el: '#status_table_1',
  data: deepcopy(pre_data),
  methods: {
    error: function() { return pre_methods.error(this); },
    load: function(a, b, c) { return pre_methods.load(this, a, b, c); },
  },
  computed: {
    comp_prop: function() { return pre_computed.comp_prop(this); }
  }
}
```

which makes it much slimmer, but there's still lots of duplication and it just *feels* wrong...

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why two apps? Sounds like you can just have one app with two components.

Comment: That's a good point, I'll give it a go!